# Automatic power on my server

Tags: power, windows-server-2008-r2, power-management, dell-poweredge

I have a problem with electricity in my company (common cuts) how can I make my server (**DELL POWEREDGE 2900**) starts automatically when the electricity is restored and I'm not there

Comment: Is not it better to use UPS that will not allow your server to shutdown?) Some servers have ability to boot by timer in BIOS setup. I am not sure your server has it.

Comment: My UPS which I use keep only 4 hours ! that's why I think to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [hardware manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-2900_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf) you can set the option under the System Security screen in the BIOS settings:

```
AC Power Recovery (Last default)

Determines how the system reacts when power is restored to the system. If
system is set to Last, the system returns to the last power state. On 
turns on the system after power is restored. When set to Off, the system
remains off after power is restored.
```